# Woocommerce checkout page issue - Payment methods not loading - strange “Credit/Debit Card Secure Payment” form

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a strange issue on a woocommerce checkout page. I tried to search online but i couldn't find a similar case. It happens that the payment methods can't load and, in place of them, a strange "Credit/Debit Card Secure Payment" form appears below the order details. Below I attached (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/brXLY.png) the console log where it shows this error: "GET https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js?ver=1 net::ERR_ABORTED 404". No errors instead on the debug.log file.

I tried disabling all the plugins except for Woocommerce and also switching to the Twenty Twenty-One theme. The result was that no more JS errors appear on the console but still the strange form remains there! (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK1gg.png)

Maybe an AJAX related issue? Please help me to find out a solution!

Thanks!

Comment: [Here's another case](https://motopress.com/forums/topic/desactivar-formulario-credit-debit-card-secure-payment/). I'd guess you've been hacked, sorry, and it's malicious code someone has added to trick your customers into sending them money.

Comment: As for the jQuery UI error I'm not sure that's related, although it might be worth checking that i18n is a genuine jQuery UI component - I'm not sure.

Comment: I'd search your code for "Credit/Debit Card Secure Payment" in all of the files in your site to see if you can find where it's come from. If you can't, you can try looking at the checkout form to see which action has been hooked and searching for that. If you can't find either then I'd guess it's malicious. But if you can then hopefully you can work out where it came from and how to get rid of it - I may be wrong about being hacked after all.